# Error Booting Ubuntu / Windows 7 on Laptop

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2, bootloader

I tried a lot of guides and walkthrough I found on the net, but my problem still persist:

I installed the UBUNTU 14.04 LTS release, and installed side by side my Windows Installation.

When I finish the installation, I reboot the computer and grub goes in rescue mode telling me "error: unknown filesystem".
I already restarted the computer e tried to repair by boot-repair, but I still have the same issue.

[BootRepair log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9282886/)

However I think the GRUB doesn't go on stage 2 because it try to read the partition and give the error message.

- EDIT: Still no answers???

Comment: Boot-Repair's log of grub's reinstall says no error and it reinstalled in i386-pc platform which is the BIOS version. Did you use ext3 instead of ext4 for a reason. It should still work but ext4 is much better. Is BIOS set for AHCI? Or is system so old that it does not have AHCI and then you may have issues with any boot files beyond the IDE limit of 137GB, but that is for some very old BIOS.

Comment: I used ext3 just to make a try, with ext4 I've the exact same result. I tried also to execute the command "ls" on all partitions, but I get always the error "Unknown Filesystem"

Comment: I'll double check the AHCI thing, but I think it's not that old. However i'll give it a chance

Answer (score 0):

Did you install Ubuntu in UEFI MODE?

If you didnt install ubuntu in UEFI mode, it wont update grub and detect your Windows partition folder, since your ubuntu is in Legacy.

Try changing boot order through BIOS - > UEFI/Legacy and set windows to first
Try enable/disable secure boot

Comment: No, the Laptop where I Installed it, has no UEFI support.

Comment: Did installation completed successfully?
Can you boot into windows?

Comment: try regenrate grub file or update grub2

Comment: I already did twice without success. The message I have is always "unknown filesystem"